# Machine code instruction anatomy

Tags: machine-code

I'm a student studying microcontrollers, and everything is generally fine, however when it came to learning the 32 bit instructions, it was somewhat glossed over. I figured after playing around with machine code it may become a bit more apparent, however I still don't quite understand why it appears so random. Some commands are perfectly normal, such as the register values, and are rather simple to understand. However other commands are fragmented and seemingly randomly distributed throughout the instruction.

[image: What we were taught]

Is there a method to the madness, or any particular tricks to figure out which bits in a given instruction belong to which command?

Comment: Yes, you need the reference manual for the processor. There is no other way to understand machine code.

Comment: Precisely! And you really want to work in hex, because that's what everyone else uses as well. Binary is too convoluted to work with.

Comment: @dom0 I know that's true generally of binary data, but is it even true in the case of an instruction like this? If that second nibble were `1101`, I can't imagine `D` is a more useful representation; I would guess that the only thing one could do with `D` is to mentally translate it to `1101`.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions are meant to be directly processed by a piece of hardware, every bit of the instruction actually setting hardware lines high or low. Obviously the instruction must be constructed in such a way that it configures the hardware to get the job done. And as hardware, especially processors, are expensive to design it makes sense to have the hardware define the format of the instruction.

So every architecture will have its own instruction format. And as was stated in the comments, you will find that format in the reference documents. Other than that I cannot think of anything more to add.